# What's wrong with my animate place-image program?

Tags: racket

I've been working on this piece of code in racket to make this rocket go up depending on the angle you enter in rocket-movie. I think something is off with my math as the rocket in the animate scene keeps going off in the wrong directions. I can't seem to figure out what exactly is wrong though. The only direction that seems to work is 20 degrees. The rocket image itself sits at 90 degrees. Could anybody help me with the place-image formula I worked on? I don't know what's wrong.

Thanks for your time.

```
#lang racket
(require 2htdp/image)
(require 2htdp/universe)
(require rackunit)

;; (make−takeoff angle) −> (−> natural−number/c image?)
;; angle : exact−integer?

(define make-takeoff
    (lambda (angle)
        (let ([side-length 400])
            (let ([the−background (square side-length "solid" "white")]
                  [the-rocket .]
                  [the-velocity (/ side-length 100)])
                (lambda (frame)
                    (place-image
                        (rotate angle the-rocket)
                        (- 375 (* (cos (- 90 angle)) (* frame the-velocity)))  
                        (- 375 (* (sin (- 90 angle)) (* frame the-velocity)))  
                        the−background))))))

;; (rocket−movie angle) −> natural−number/c
;; angle : exact−integer?
(define rocket-movie
    (lambda (angle)
        (animate (make-takeoff angle))))
```

Answer (score 4):

Forgive me for being pedantic, but you *really, really* need to break up your "make-takeoff" function into smaller pieces.  In particular, if you'd written a "rocket-x" function that accepted the angle and the frame, you could write test cases for it, and figure out the problem yourself.  Let me know if you run into any trouble doing this.

Comment: I think you are right about that. I'm going to give it a shot. I'll update this if I get any troubles. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note: the [*cos*](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._cos%29%29) and [*sin*](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._sin%29%29) functions work in **radians**, not degrees.  Your calculations appear to assume degrees, and that should explain why you're seeing weird values.

(On the other hand, [*rotate*](http://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage.html#%28def._%28%28lib._2htdp/image..rkt%29._rotate%29%29) does work with numbers assuming that they are in degrees.  So just be careful: numbers can mean different things depending on context.)